# MYSQL How would you get distinct along with its count

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

How would you get list of each distinct UUID along with its count

```
SELECT DISTINCT uuid, COUNT(uuid) as count FROM log;

id  uuid
|  1 | a846        
|  2 | a846
|  3 | a846
|  4 | a846
|  5 | b307
|  6 | b307
|  7 | b307                                                               
|  8 | b307
|  9 | b307                                                           
| 10 | b307
```

Expected result

```
a846 4
b307 6
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use `group by`!

```
select uuid, count(*) cnt from log group by uuid
```